# Probability of rolling a specific number on a dice 2+ times in x throws

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

Would need help with a probability calculations question

if I have a 25 face dice and I roll it 62 times, what is the probability that at least 2 times I roll a 5? How about If I roll it 30 times?

What's the actual formula for calculating the probability of rolling a specific number on a dice 2+ times in x throws?

Edit:

1. So if this is the correct formula $\binom{n}{k}p^kq^{n−k}$, what would represent $n$, $k$, $p$, $q$ in my situation? Sorry, it's been 20 years since I've graduated Uni, and haven't used these formulas since, so they are a foreign language now.

Comment: 1 - (probability of it occurring **exactly** 0 times) - (probability of it occurring **exactly** 1 time).  See [Binomial Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution), 
specifically $\displaystyle \binom{n}{k}p^kq^{(n-k)}.$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Identifying the problem as a Binomial Distribution helped. Using Online BD calculators (https://stattrek.com/online-calculator/binomial) I've managed to find the answers I need. Thank you

Comment: It would be nice for this question if you posted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have found the right formula, yes. To be precise, the probability of rolling $5$ on a $25$-sided die at least $2$ times in $n$ throws is $\sum_{k=2}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(\frac{1}{25})^k(\frac{24}{25})^{n-k}$. Matching terms in this expression with those of your formula answers the questions posed in your edit: $n$ represents the total number of times you toss the die, $k$ represents the number of "successes" ("success" defined here as rolling a $5$) you wish to calculate the probability of, $p$ represents the raw probability of success ($1$ in $25$) and $q$ represents the probability of failure.

Comment: It is much simpler to compute the probability as $1-\sum_{k=0}^{1}\binom{n}{k}(\frac{1}{25})^k(\frac{24}{25})^{n-k}$.

Comment: @user I realise that. My main goal was to clear up OP's confusion as outlined in their edit, not necessarily to efficiently compute said probability, and the form I used is better for that.